# Multiply a list of lists by a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, multiplication

i want to multiply a list of lists such as ([2,3,6],[3,4,9],[4,8,13]) by another list, which will also have the same number of lists as the first set of lists, i.e, the first list of lists may have 3 lists, each with a list of 5 numbers, but the second list will have 3 numbers, each multiplying the elements of the rows of the first list. e.g

```
([2,3,6],[3,4,9],[4,8,13]) with [2,3,4]
```

would result in

```
([4,6,12],[9,12,27],[16,32,52])
```

so far i have

```
sol = [inv[i]*bb[i] for i in range(len(inv[i]))]
        return sol
```

where inv[i] is my list of lists and bb is my list.

i want this so that it can be done for any lenght of list in bb, and inv[i] as long as they are both the same length

thanks guys

UPDATE:

i added in pound's solution and fiddled around a bit

it now prints

```
[20.0, -9.0, -3.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
[3.0, -2.0, -0.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
[-8.0, 4.0, 1.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
[40.0, -18.0, -6.0]
```

for this code:

```
print (inv[i])

       sol = []
       for i, item in enumerate(inv):
           sol.append(map(lambda x: x*bb[i], item))

           print sol[i]
```

how do i get rid of the bullshit stuff and keep the last 3 lines seen only?

Comment: Did you try unindenting `print sol[i]`, and replacing it with: `print sol` (omit the `[i]`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

L = [[2,3,6],[3,4,9],[4,8,13]]
M = [2,3,4]
[[i*j for i,j in zip(subl, subm)] for subl, subm in zip(L, itertools.cycle([M]))]
```

Ouptut:

```
Out[101]: [[4, 9, 24], [6, 12, 36], [8, 24, 52]]
```

Without itertools:

```
answer = []
for subl in L:
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(subl)):
        temp.append(subl[i] * M[i])
    answer.append(temp)
```

Output:

```
In [103]: answer
Out[103]: [[4, 9, 24], [6, 12, 36], [8, 24, 52]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
big = [[2,3,6],[3,4,9],[4,8,13]]
small = [2,3,4]

res = []

for i, item in enumerate(big):
    res.append(map(lambda x: x*small[i], item))

print res
```

Output:

```
[[4, 6, 12], [9, 12, 27], [16, 32, 52]]
```

Comment: sol.append(map(lambda x: x*bb[i], item))
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration    is what i get - and the input for the list is not defined. it could be any random value inout in shell. i have made it a def function

Comment: for i in xrange(len(inv)):

        print (inv[i])

        inverse = inv[i]

        sol = []

        for i, item in enumerate(inverse):

            sol.append(map(lambda x: x*bb[i], item))

            print sol

i changed big and small to match my variables..


the top part is after i finished some calculations

Comment: Can you edit your answer and format the code? I can't read your comment.

Comment: UPDATE: i have managed to get it to print it properly, but it prints a load of unnecessary things before hand...i'll post it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy library:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = np.array([[2,3,6],[3,4,9],[4,8,13]])
list2 = np.array([2,3,4])
result = list1 * list2.transpose()
result_list = result.tolist()
```

Or without numpy:

```
list1 = [[2,3,6],[3,4,9],[4,8,13]]
list2 = [2,3,4]
result_list = list1[:]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    result_list[i] = [x * list2[i] for x in result_list[i]]
```

Comment: Nice, but "sorry, i want to try to do this without any imports if possible..." - OP

Comment: Why looking for difficult solutions? Numpy is nice and easy, plus Numpy library is implemented in C and is very fast, while Python loops are very slow. Just compare the performance on larger lists ;)

Comment: Lol. Once you use numpy, you never go back I guess... ;)

Comment: @Pound, yea, unless it is combined with Python loops